# CALayer and CGGradientRef anti-aliasing?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, gradient, antialiasing, radial-gradients

I'm having an odd issue with CALayer drawing for the iPhone.  I have a root layer which adds a bunch of sublayers representing "bubbles".  The end result is supposed to look something like this:

[http://www.expensivedna.com/IMG_0018.PNG http://www.expensivedna.com/IMG_0018.PNG](http://www.expensivedna.com/IMG_0018.PNG)

The problem is that I can't seem to get the layer to anti-alias (notice the jaggies on the bubbles).  My code overwriting drawInContext for the bubble CALayer is as follows:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)theContext{
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(theContext, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(theContext, true);

size_t num_locations = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
CGFloat components[8] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5,  // Start color
                          1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 }; // End color
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef glossGradient = 
CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(25, 20);
CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(25, 25);
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(theContext, glossGradient, midCenter, 20, topCenter, 10, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
```

}

Now the really odd thing is that if I slightly alter the drawing code to only draw normal red circles as follows:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)theContext{
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(theContext, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(theContext, true);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(theContext, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(theContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, 40,40));
}
```

Everything seems to antialias OK:

[http://www.expensivedna.com/IMG_0017.PNG http://www.expensivedna.com/IMG_0017.PNG](http://www.expensivedna.com/IMG_0017.PNG)

I can't seem to figure out this seemingly odd behavior.  Am I missing some difference between antialiasing gradients and normal circles?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks guys.  So it turns out that the answer is a combination of your two answers (coob and Alex).  Basically it seems like the CGDrawRadialGradient function only has aliasing at the starting circle, not the ending one.  Since I want aliased "edges" on both, I first set the function to draw from the inside out which takes care of the first "edge", but produces the following:

[Step 1](http://www.expensivedna.com/pic2.png)

Then, I clip the image as suggested by coob and that gives a nice aliasing around the final edge of the bubble:

[Step 2](http://www.expensivedna.com/pic1.png)

Looks good enough for me!

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)theContext{
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(theContext, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(theContext, true);

size_t num_locations = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
CGFloat components[8] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0,  // Start color
              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5 }; // End color
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef glossGradient = 
CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(theContext, CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40));
CGContextClip(theContext);

CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(25, 20);
CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(25, 25);
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(theContext, glossGradient, topCenter, 10, midCenter, 20, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Jeff - make topCenter a bit further out and use CGContextClipToMask with a circular mask.

Edit: Actually a much much better way to do it is to use a vector clipping path using CGContextClip.

Edit 2: Sample code:

```
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(theContext, CGRectMake(20, 20, 10, 10));
CGContextClip(theContext);
```

Add this before you draw your gradient, and draw it a bit further out.

Comment: tip: Had to inset my rect by a 1 point to completely eliminate jaggies here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try dropping out the kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation? It might be doing something weird with the alpha